# How to resume a paused workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, powershell, designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint 2010 style workflow in SharePoint 2013. It is currently paused till 10 Dec 2018 and says "Paused until 2018/12/10"

Is it possible to resume this workflow before that date by using some kind of PowerShell or something? Like if I want to resume this workflow on 5th Dec, can it be done?